# How does the layout XML properly get the names from a 'values' XML?

Tags: android, xml

I added a colors.xml file to my /values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
    <item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
    <integer-array name="androidcolors">
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/purple</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

In my layout file, I am able to reference these colors by using @color/colorname:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/cameraViewHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"/>
```

My question is how does it know that @color/blue ties back to the colors.xml?

What does  `<integer-array name="androidcolors">` actually do? What happens do "androidcolors", why don't I need to do @color/androidcolors.blue or something?

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning with android but the documentation helped me lots with same problem but with the @strings folder.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Hope that helps!